# Knockout js visible binding does not seem to be working

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I am new to Knockout and am creating a prototype.  I am attempting to use the visible binding on a div to only display when I click a "menu option".  However, when I create the condition it does not seem to work.

Here is my source:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/knockout.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Models.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                function BillingInformation() {
                    this.accountNumber = ko.observable('4111111111111111');
                    this.cardType = ko.observable('Visa');
                    this.expirationDate = ko.observable('2016-01-15');
                }

                function Invoice(billingDate, amount, paid) {
                    this.billingDate = billingDate;
                    this.amount = amount;
                    this.paid = paid;
                }

                function Pet(name, breed, age) {
                    this.name = name;
                    this.breed = breed;
                    this.age = age;
                }

                function PrototypeViewModel() {
                    this.menu = [{ folderName: 'Customer Information', folderId: 0 },
                                 { folderName: 'Customer Information Edit', folderId: 1 },
                                 { folderName: 'Billing Information Edit', folderId: 2 },
                                 { folderName: 'Pets', folderId: 3 }, 
                                 { folderName: 'Invoices', folderId: 4 }];

                    this.customer = { firstName: 'Wesley', lastName: 'Snipes', email: 'wsnipes@gmail.com' };

                    this.billingInformation = new BillingInformation();

                    this.pets = ko.observableArray(
                        [
                            new Pet('Poopy', 'Great Dane', 3),
                            new Pet('Pokey', 'Great Dane', 2)
                        ]);

                    this.invoices = ko.observableArray(
                        [
                            new Invoice('2012-11-15', 24.35, true),
                            new Invoice('2012-12-15', 24.35, true),
                            new Invoice('2013-01-15', 34.43, false)
                        ]);

                    this.selectedMenuOptionId = ko.observable();
                    this.selectMenuOption = function (menuOption) {
                        this.selectedMenuOptionId = menuOption.folderId;
                    };

                    this.isMenuSelected = function(menuSelected) {
                        return this.selectedMenuOptionId == menuSelected;
                    };
                }

                ko.applyBindings(new PrototypeViewModel());
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: menu">
            <li data-bind="text: $data.folderName, click: $root.selectMenuOption"></li>
        </ul>

        <div data-bind="visible: isMenuSelected(0)">
            <p>selected customer menu</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried to simply set the visible condition to do a string compare but that did not seem to work.  As you can see now, I am using the isMenuSelected function in an attempt to make it work but that failed as well.  I am not getting any script errors either.  Please, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have implemented `isMenuSelected` with

```
this.isMenuSelected = function(menuSelected) {
    return this.selectedMenuOptionId == menuSelected;
};
```

but I believe you need to do something more like

```
this.isMenuSelected = ko.computed(function () {
    return this.selectedMenuOptionId == menuSelected;
});
```

Comment: This worked! So thank you.  The funny thing is that it did not work initially.  I had to create a variable called self (got the idea from the knockout tutorial) and set it to 'this'.  After that, it worked fully!

Comment: Yeah, the difference between `self` and `this` seems a little arcane at first. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

KnockoutJS only works if the binding is made in a way to make is observable and view dependent on the model. Here in your code, the `this.isMenuSelected` is declared as a function and not an observable. Rather than giving it a definition of a function, give it a definition of observable function. So you need to define it as

```
this.isMenuSelected = ko.computed(function () {
                       ...
                      });
```

Previously, **ko.computed** was called as `ko.dependentObservable`. Just to let you know if you have used earlier versions, then it won't be a new thing for you.